# Pharo 2.0 Smalltalk and PostgresV2

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Trying to return results from a table in a DB.
This code works:

```
| connection results |

PGConnection defaultConnectionArgs
hostname: '*****.awebservice.com';
portno: 1234;
databaseName: '*****';
userName: '********';
password: '**************'.

connection := PGConnection new.

connection startup.
results := connection execute: 'SELECT uid, code, name FROM public.Project'.
Transcript show: results rows.
```

But in analysing it I want to know how to access a single row. Where in Smalltalk classes is ROWS?
If I do further processing of the `OrderedCollection` returned (results) with this code:

```
results rows do: [:row | | data |
data := row dataKeyedByFieldName.
Transcript show: 'Uid: ''', (data at: 'uid') , ''''; cr.
Transcript show: 'Code: ''', (data at: 'code') , ''''; cr.
Transcript show: 'Name: ''', (data at: 'name') , ''''; cr; cr]. 
connection terminate.
```

I get an error: `Instances of SmallInteger are not indexable`.
I will come clean and say I got this off the web but nowhere can I find either ROWS or DATAKEYEDBYFIELDNAME as methods in any Smalltalk class.

Edit:
OK I found out that the return variable from connection: execute is of type `PGAsciiRow` and the method `#dataKeyedByFieldName` is to enable iteration by using name index instead of simple numeric. But still don't know where the error is coming from.
The following is a stack trace:

```
    errorNotIndexable
    "Create an error notification that the receiver is not indexable."
    self error: ('Instances of {1} are not indexable'
    translated format: {self class name})
```

Comment: there is Pharo 5.0 maybe 3.0?

Comment: Pharo 3.0 is better than Pharo 5.0?

Comment: There is NO Pharo 5. Current stable is 2.0, to be released is 3.0 (see http://www.pharo-project.org/home)

Comment: `Instances of SmallInteger are not indexable` means that you are trying to send `#at:` or a similar message to `SmallInteger`. Without seeing the stack there is very little we can do to help you. Try right clicking on a stack frame entry in the debugger and copying the stack to clipboard, then paste that here (at least the first 20 or so lines).

Comment: errorNotIndexable
 "Create an error notification that the receiver is not indexable."

 self error: ('Instances of {1} are not indexable' translated format: {self class name})

Comment: That's not the stack, that's the method that throws the error. When you're in the debugger, the debugger is split horizontally, with the method pointed to by the stack frame at the bottom (the method source) and the list of stack frames at the top. Right click on the topmost entry in the stack frame list and select `copy to clipboard`. That's what we need. If you're stuck, checkout the IRC channel #pharo on irc.freenode.net.

Comment: Thanks for the headbanging help. Solved it by changing the first Transcript show line to read:        Transcript show: 'Uid: '; show: (data at: 'uid'), ''''; cr. Obviously didn't like using comma with show: when a variable is a SmallInteger but is OK when they are Strings.

Answer (score 1):

most probably

```
data at: 'uid'
```

(or 'code') is answering an integer number. Then, this line:

```
Transcript show: 'Uid: ''', (data at: 'uid') , ''''; cr.
```

should better be written:

```
Transcript show: 'Uid: ''', (data at: 'uid') asString, ''''; cr.
```

something like that :)